# What is the best way to search in sql with multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables on my tables and I want to search from them from a phrase split in whitespaces

example: The quick brown.

first it will search the phrase "The quick brown" then "The", "quick", "brown"

My approach is to union all the table then search.

```
SELECT body FROM
(SELECT body FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT body FROM table2)
) AS row WHERE body LIKE '%The quick brown%' OR body LIKE '%The%' OR body LIKE '%quick%' OR body LIKE '%brown%'
```

What is the best way to do that with higher in speed?

By the way I'm using MySQL

Comment: search for `FULL-TEXT Search`\

Comment: If I'am correct if I search for full text it will just search for "The quick brown"

Comment: that's the literal full-text search and that's not what I mean. [click this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few observations:

- because you have `OR`s between your clauses, your query will always perform the `like %the%` clause for example, which always includes and gives you a broader result than your most restricting clause. A thing which i assume you don't want.
- since you have clauses which begin with %, you are guaranteed to have full table scans there, even if you'd not have those full table unions there.

I think that the best solution would be to add a full text search component like sphinx to your technology stack, since that can do those kind of searches and return weighted results, based on complex algoritms.